# cannot launch and create AVD in android

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

### **I am trying to run my a simple helloworld in andriod but while lunching AVD it throws an error saying.**

---

> Failed to install nischal.apk on device 'emulator-5556!  (null) 
>   Failed to install nischal.apk on device 'emulator-5556': EOF 
>   com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF  Launch canceled!

**I also tried to create a new AVD but still it throws an error saying**

> Could not create file
>   'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.android\avd\nischalAVD.avd\sdcard.img':
>   No such file or directory Failed to create the SD card.  Failed to
>   create sdcard in the AVD folder.

***so please can anyone help me to figure out the problem.***
***thank you for your help..***

Answer (score 0):

Try it as administrator, maybe you don't have permissions to write on C:.

Comment: I am using as a adminstrator.Some time AVD runs and some time it doesnt.

Comment: If you don't need the SD card, don't create one?
Not really a solution, but worth a try.

Comment: Hey XST,
I have sloved the problem by ending adb.exe service,cleaning and running the project.